# How do you define the vertical and horizontal relationship between views using the Masonry DSL for Auto Layout?

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios-autolayout

With Apple's Visual Format Language, it's pretty simple to set the horizontal and vertical relationships between views and their superview using spacers.

If I wanted view2 in the visual example below to have a fixed width, while view1 will fill the remaining space. With VFL I would specify this behavior as follows:

|-[view1]-[view2(==100)-|

[image: visual example of layout I want to achieve with Masonry]

With Masonry, it's not as clear how to establish these relationships between views; view1 is not 'aware' of view2 and will either undershoot or overlap it. What am I missing?

Comment: What masonry are you referring to? The JavaScript library?

Comment: Different Masonry. Yeah it's confusing. https://github.com/Masonry/Masonry

Comment: Never knew about it! That could have made my life easier so many times...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views are still 'aware' of each other. The key is to pin the left edge of view2 to the right edge of view1:

```
[view1 mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.top.bottom.left.equalTo(containerView);
        }];

[view2 mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.top.bottom.equalTo(containerView);
            make.left.equalTo(view1.mas_right);
            make.right.equalTo(containerView);
            make.width.equalTo(@100);
        }];
```